# Aggregate results from select queries

Tags: mysql, select, aggregate

I have a table with three columns: `id`, `date`, `state`.

For each unique value of `id`, I would like to select `date` and `state`, multiply the state array by a scalar variable for each id defined from else, and then sum up the `state` arrays where the `date` column is the same value.

How would this be achieved in a mysql statement?

Example:

```
SELECT scal_val FROM table1 WHERE id = 413 into @scal_val;
SELECT date, state * @scal_val as a FROM table2 WHERE id = 413
# now need to loop through ids in table2 for each id, adding state*@scal_val each time
```

table1:

```
╭───╥────────────┬─────────────╮
│   ║     id     │  scal_val   │
╞═══╬════════════╪═════════════╡
│ A ║ 413        │ 250         │
│ B ║ 414        │ 50          │
│ C ║ 415        │ 10          │
└───╨────────────┴─────────────┘
```

table2:

```
╭───╥────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────╮
│   ║     id     │    date     │    state    │
╞═══╬════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════╡
│ A ║ 413        │ 2016-01-01  │       1     │
│ B ║ 413        │ 2016-01-02  │       0     │
│ C ║ 413        │ 2016-01-03  │       1     │
│ D ║ 414        │ 2016-01-01  │       1     │
│ E ║ 414        │ 2016-01-02  │       1     │
│ F ║ 414        │ 2016-01-03  │       1     │
│ G ║ 415        │ 2016-01-01  │       1     │
│ H ║ 415        │ 2016-01-02  │       0     │
│ I ║ 415        │ 2016-01-03  │       0     │
└───╨────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┘
```

result:

```
╭───╥────────────┬─────────────╮
│   ║   date     │    state    │
╞═══╬════════════╪═════════════╡
│ A ║ 2016-01-01 │ 310         │
│ B ║ 2016-01-01 │ 50          │
│ C ║ 2016-01-01 │ 300         │ 
└───╨────────────┴─────────────┘
```

MySQL version 5.6.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.`date`, SUM(t1.scal_val * t2.state) state
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY t2.`date`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the following.

```
SELECT table2.date, SUM(IFNULL(table1.scal_val,0) * table2.state) 
FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1
ON table1.id = table2.id
GROUP BY table2.date
```

Comment: No scalar value - no sum, so LEFT join and IFNULL are excess I think...

Comment: Yes you are correct. Thank you for the remark.

Comment: There is one more reason why IFNULL is excess. With it according multiplying result is `0` and do not affect on the sum. Without it (simple `SUM(table1.scal_val * table2.state)`) according multiplying result is `NULL`, but such aggregate functions as SUM, COUNT, etc. ignores/skippes `NULL` values, so it do not affect on the sum again.

Comment: Nevertheless your query may make sense - in the case when the author needs to obtain all dates listed in `table2`, even if no `ID`s with according `scal_val` for that date. But in most cases it is more safe to generate according dates list within the range using recursive CTE or another technique.